# Code to automate copying selection to new File and autosave

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I am trying to write some code that selects a range of cells, different every time, that exports it to a new file with a predefined file name except for the `weeknumber`.

I first make a selection of the cells I want by filtering on `weeknumber`.

After that I use to following code to export it to a new file;

```
Sub Exportplanning()

Dim strFileName As String

strFileName = "Uitvoeringsplanning BRTTI 2014 week " & InputBox("Geef de desbetreffende weken aan en geef aan of het om voorlopig gaat (v) of definitief (def) Uitvoeringsplanning BRTTI 2014 week ..", "Geef de bestandsnaam op")
If Trim(strFileName) = vbNullString Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

ActiveSheet.Copy
With ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Cells.Select
Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
.Parent.SaveAs "D:\rpreijnd\Desktop\" & strFileName & ".xlsx", xlOpenXMLWorkbook
.Parent.Close False
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The problem is that I want the new file to be without the hidden rows and colums. I can't seem to get it right.

Also I want the cells in the new file to be as value and not as formula, I tried some code, but It messed the whole file up.

The other problem is that when I hit the cancel button it still generates a file. What is the right code to get the action to stop if I hit cancel?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new workbook to save with the new information as Follows:

```
Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook

Workbooks.Add NewWorkbook

NewWorkbook.SaveAs (Filename)
```

If you want to past only values from the source file use this:

```
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```